# Django & Celery use a singleton class instance attribute as a global

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

I am looking to do this:

I have 2 functions in the same module (same file even):

```
def a():
    while(True):
         //do something
         if global_var:
              //do something else!

def b():
    global_var = some_function_result
```

I was given the idea of using a singleton class as a storage for a global.

*(I did try using a module level global with the same result)*

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = 1

@shared_task
def add_var():
    myclass = MyClass()
    while(1):
        myclass.flag += 1
        print myclass.flag

@shared_task
def print_var():
    myclass = MyClass()
    while(1):
        print myclass.flag
```

Result:

**print_var keeps printing 1 and add_var keeps adding 1 but its not reflecting in print_var**

Edit:

Missed mentioning sooner important info:
I'm running these processes on celery - and now I've come to understand that celery and django run on separate threads. 
But when I run both in celery, I still don't see the effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if that is all you want to achieve you do not need a singleton; a (static) class attribute will do the job:

```
class MyClass(object):

    FLAG = 1

@shared_task
def add_var():
    myclass = MyClass()
    while(1):
        myclass.FLAG += 1
        print( myclass.FLAG )

@shared_task
def print_var():
    myclass = MyClass()
    while(1):
        print( myclass.FLAG )
```

Comment: Same result. The value doesn't seem to change.
So I tried running this in shell - called add_var(), then exited after a few seconds - flag value was in the thousands - now when I do MyClass.FLAG its still 1

Comment: then what does the rest of your code do? what is `@shared_task`?

Comment: Celery - its running asynchronously using .delay()